# Codeigniter: MySQL Where Clause and Quotes

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter

**Query in CodeIgniter**:

```
$this->db->select('comments.created_at, comments.section_id, comments.submittedby_id, users.username, comments.text, sections.name');
$this->db->order_by('comments.created_at', 'desc');
$this->db->where('comments.submittedby_id',  'users.user_id'); 
$this->db->where('comments.section_id', 'sections.id'); 

$query = $this->db->get(array('comments', 'users', 'sections'),10);
```

**Produce SQL Request**:

> SELECT `pdb_comments`.`created_at`,
>   `pdb_comments`.`section_id`,
>   `pdb_comments`.`submittedby_id`,
>   `pdb_users`.`username`,
>   `pdb_comments`.`text`,
>   `pdb_sections`.`name` FROM
>   (`pdb_comments`, `pdb_users`,
>   `pdb_sections`) WHERE
>   `pdb_comments`.`submittedby_id` =
>   'users.user_id' AND
>   `pdb_comments`.`section_id` =
>   'sections.id' ORDER BY
>   `pdb_comments`.`created_at` desc LIMIT
>   10

The issue is that the database prefix (`pdb_`) does not get added in the `WHERE` clause. I can manually insert the prefix by appending `$this->db->dbprefix`, but this doesn't fix the main problem.

**Quotes**:

```
`pdb_comments`.`submittedby_id` = 'pdb_users.user_id'
```

The quotes on the right side are not accurate, and generate 0 results for me. Is there any way to make CodeIgniter recognize the second half of the where clause as a piece of my table; thereby adding the database prefix, and properly placing the quotes by avoiding two joins? Is there another way to do this? Thanks in advance.

--

Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$this->db->select('comments.created_at, comments.section_id, comments.submittedby_id, users.username, comments.text, sections.name');
$this->db->from('comments');
$this->db->join('users', 'comments.submittedby_id=users.user_id'); 
$this->db->join('sections', 'comments.section_id=sections.id'); 
$this->db->order_by('comments.created_at', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

instead.

Comment: i'm trying to avoid the joins to reduce overhead.  not possible?  or not needed?

Comment: What you were trying to accomplish is still a join; not an explicit join (is doesn't use the "join" keyword), but a join nevertheless. You should use explicit joins, to make your code more readable. Also, use EXPLAIN sql_statement, in your favourite client to see how the query is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a dumb question, but why don't you just write the SQL directly?  The interface doesn't look like it's giving you anything but clutter.

Comment: nice to use the CI calls instead -- gives me flexibility with DB prefixes, etc.